# Is this set a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

Tags: probability, general-topology

Does, $P= \{ A: A \in  \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \sum _j a_{i,j}=1\,\forall i, 0 \le a_{i,j}\le 1 \}$ form a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ ?

In other words, I am looking at a those matrices $A$ such that every row of $A$ is a probability distribution over some finite set say $G$.

Thank you

Comment: $P$ is the continuous preimage of a closed set, thus closed.

Comment: Nice first question. Would you please change R^{mxn} to $\mathbb R^{m \times n}$.

Comment: @user251257 : the function that $P$ is the preimage of is a little complicated (try to explicit it), and the continuity may not be obvious

Comment: Thank you all. Now I see this.

Comment: @Tryss it is just sum and projection, both continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each set

$$U_{i,j} = \{ A : 0 \leq a_{i,j} \leq 1 \}$$

is closed, as it is the preimage of the closed set $[0,1]$ by a continuous function

So the set

$$U= \bigcap_{i,j} B_{i,j} $$

is closed too

Each set

$$V_i= \{ A : \sum_j a_{i,j} = 1 \}$$

is closed, as the preimage of the closed set $\{1\}$ by a continuous function

So the set

$$ V = \bigcap_i V_i $$

Is closed

And $P = U \cap V$, so it is closed